# WriteConsole doesn't work with PowerShell ISE?

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, winapi, console

[`WriteConsole`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole) does not work with PowerShell ISE.

Neither `WriteConsoleW` or `WriteConsoleA` do.

See, for example, this program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

void w() {
  DWORD written;
  BOOL const success = WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), L"Printed\n", 8, &written, nullptr);
  std::wcout << (success ? L"Success" : L"Failure") << L". Wrote " << written << L" characters." << std::endl;
}

void a() {
  DWORD written;
  BOOL const success = WriteConsoleA(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), "Printed\n", 8, &written, nullptr);
  std::cout << (success ? "Success" : "Failure") << ". Wrote " << written << " characters." << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  w();
  a();
  return 0;
}
```

Ran from PowerShell (or Command Prompt, or Git Bash), it prints:

```
Printed
Success (wrote 8 characters)
Printed
Success (wrote 8 characters)
```

But from PowerShell ISE:

```
Failure (wrote 0 characters)
Failure (wrote 0 characters)
```

Answer (score 4):

To provide background information on [Bertie Wheen's own helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70543376/45375):

- Perhaps surprisingly, the **Windows PowerShell ISE does *not* allocate a console *by default***. (The console-*like* UI that the ISE presents is not a true Windows console).
- A **console is allocated *on demand***, the first time a console-subsystem program is run in a session (e.g., `cmd /c ver`)

  - Even once that has happened, however, ***interactive* console-subsystem programs are fundamentally unsupported** (try `choice /m "Prompt me"`, for instance).

Interactively, you can test if a console has been allocated or not with the following command: `[Console]::WindowTop`; if there's no console, you'll get a `The handle is invalid` error.

---

It follows from the above that **your program cannot assume that a console is present when run in the ISE**.

**One option is to simply not support running in the ISE**, given that it is:

- [no longer actively developed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support)
- and [there are various reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 6+, and the limitations with respect to console-subsystem programs mentioned above.

As for a successor environment: The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

---

As for the potential **reason for the poor console support in the ISE**: [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) notes:

> A possible reason why ISE developers choose not to allocate a console could stem from the historic difficulties of creating a custom, embedded console within an app's own window. Developers had to resort to [hackish, unsupported ways](https://github.com/rprichard/winpty) of doing that. Only recently (2018) Windows got a dedicated [pseudo-console (ConPTY) API](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-introducing-the-windows-pseudo-console-conpty/).

Answer (score 3):

The reason why is shown by this program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

int main() {
  DWORD const file_type = GetFileType(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE));
  if (file_type == FILE_TYPE_CHAR) {
    std::cout << "char" << std::endl;
  } else if (file_type == FILE_TYPE_PIPE) {
    std::cout << "pipe" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << file_type << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When run from PowerShell (or Command Prompt, or Git Bash), it prints:

```
char
```

But from PowerShell ISE:

```
pipe
```

`WriteConsole` cannot write through a pipe, and thus fails. The same thing happens when run from PowerShell / Command Prompt / Git Bash if the output is piped.